# Taskbar randomly pop up while Full Screen

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, fullscreen

Well, I have this problem which won't let me play quietly or watch movie quietly since a couple of days ago, what happens is that approximately every 15 minutes if I'm watching a movie in full screen the taskbar appears out of nowhere, the other thing is that if I'm playing the game in full screen it exits as if I had pressed the button with the Windows logo.

I have not found a specific solution to my problem but the problem according to some sites could be some event that runs every so often, so I entered Event Viewer and this is what I saw.

[image]

I did some calculations and found that the **Service Control Manager** has caused the 65.15% of the events in the last 7 days, 505 in the last 24 hours 15 in the last hour, so I guess this is what causes the problems.

I wonder, is this is normal or not?, Could this be causing the problem mentioned above?, and finally, what can I do to fix it?

I also wonder if it is normal that many events run even without the service control manager.

Comment: High activity by SCM is perfectly normal, so that cannot be the problem.

Comment: maybe an application is trying to pop up a notification?  what's the operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional 64 bits Service Pack 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> 1. Right-click each affected program's executable and go to compatibility tab. Then check the "Disable display scaling on high DPI
>    settings"
> 2. Globally fix this in the custom DPI setting. Chose the windows XP scaling mode when you set your DPI.

More detail can be found here: [Taskbar shows in full screen applications](http://tough-to-find.blogspot.com/2009/03/taskbar-shows-in-full-screen.html).

If the issue persists follow these steps to find the additional faulting application (the application faults triggering a windows events which breaks the 'screen exclusivity' of the program you were targeted in)

> Here's how to find out what application is causing the problem:
>
> 1. Do a search in the Start Menu searchbar for EVENTVWR and open the exe file.
> 2. In the middle, there should be a section called "Summary of Administrative Events". Click the + box in front of Errors.
> 3. There should be a large amount of errors reported in the last 24 hours under Application Errors. Double click the Application Errors name
> 4. Click on any of the Errors and in the grey description it should give a Faulting application name. That is your culprit application.
>    You can either uninstall that application or I'm sure there is a way
>    to turn the problem reporting off if you feel the application is
>    important or is not actually causing errors.

More detail on that can be found here:
[Windows 7: Taskbar appears while watching fullscreen video](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/213108-taskbar-appears-while-watching-fullscreen-video.html).

Answer (score 1):

Some process in the taskbar must be setting the focus to its icon to cause the
taskbar to appear.

When this happens, examine the taskbar to see if you can locate that process.

A preventive measure might be to close all unnecessary processes before viewing a video full-screen.

Answer (score 1):

The Event you are seeing in event Viewer is actually normal..
By [Microsoft Doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349381(v=ws.10).aspx)

But the problem here is its getting flooded this might be because of faulty drivers or faulty updates or faulty software's.

there are few threads available online for how to solve the 7036 Event Flood.

http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/211747-event-id-7036-flood.html

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/017cf738-d29b-4b77-aa3d-756fcdbb3a5f/event-id-7036

Here you will get the complete description of the event.

http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-7036-source-Service%20Control%20Manager-eventno-1529-phase-1.htm

Or if you can give further description and details of the actual problem will try and tell you how to solve that specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem for months, maybe longer.

FIX:

I've used many of methods to See where the problem occurs. And these methods have been useful in seeing what was actually going on. But what actually fixed the problem was ultimately just this below at 1) a clean boot; the rest are other methods I used while troubleshooting -- ultimately at 1) was my fix.

- 1) FIX -- First: How I fixed the problem: -- "A Windows clean boot". Then after, rebooted again Normal. I have manipulated my system many times with new software, programming, networking, you name it, to include modified start up. So here you can see how to do a clean boot.

thewindowsclub.com/what-is-clean-boot-state-in-windows

2) What was happening was my machine was "logging errors" and "logging info".
Can be seen in run: "EVENTVIEWER" (Windows key + keyword event). Then Administrative Events. Watch your movie and when it pops out of focus go check out the events w/regards to the time it occurred.

3) I even tried using pinning software which did nothing. Here are some more things I used along the way in trying to figure out this problem. A Focus Logger.

Focus Logger:
adminscope.com/downloads/window-focus-logger/

Nothing was actually losing focus, when this problem was occurring, but this might help someone else.

I've also used SystermInternalsSuite, and used the Autoruns.exe. I've also used ProcessExplorer, another sofware. But at the top is where I found my fix -- for me and so I'll share.

Process Explorer:
technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer ends with .aspx

SystemInternalsSuite:
technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062 ends with .aspx

Answer (score 0):

This post has been so helpful, I've been having taskbar popup intermittently for a while and could not pin down the issue. Now I've tried everything from looking through event viewer, to clean install, different OS's, but it always came back. Though with Windows Focus Viewer I was able to find what was stealing the focus away from my browser while having a video full screen and the final is called, "e_yatikae.exe" EPSON Status Monitor 3 from SEIKO EPSON CORPORATION. I went into the folder and deleted all file with the same name e_yatikae and low and behold no more taskbar intermittently popping up every 30-60 minutes.

I waiting a couple of more days just to be certain, but if this is the cause I will be sending Epson a complaint and that they need to fix the issue with this file for future updates. I'm not sure what it controls, but I can still print wirelessly with no issues and the Epson software hasn't complained. So anyone with this issue and has an Epson printer, find this file and delete it to see if it helps.

Comment: Until you have confirmed that this solution corrects the problem described in the question, it would be better to make this a comment.